# Quad textured with big texture doesn't show up

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, ati

I've run into some issue with drawing a texture. Situation is as follows:

I've got linux box with ati hardware and propietary ati driver, which is two or three years old - because of ati ditching old hw. I've got custom application with dedicated (mostly)2D engine based on opengl. (It was build over years and is quite mature, and never
got problems like this)

The problem happens, when vram (which is taken from system memory, 2GB in this particular case) is almost to maximum filed with textures. When in scene there is a quad, which is textured with texture over 2048x2048 it is not drawn. When I do timing of particular surfaces, the surface which takes most time to draw is not the one being textured with big tex (takes about 87 us), but the next one drawn after it (takes ~900 ms!).
The scene being drawn, doesn't use all the textures from vram, but only, let's say: 8%. Unfortunatelly, I cannot free even a small part of it. The application is usually working under that kind of vram-stressed conditions, and never behaved like this.

glGetError() returns nothing.
All other textures are drawn normally.

Comment: How are you measuring rendering time? With counters built into graphics driver? If not, then it's incorrect, don't trust it. Also, what is max texture size on your hardware, and what kind of draw call you are using?

Comment: I'm measuring time of single batches using gettimeofday(). I'm aware that it's not most accurate in the world, unfortunatelly - I don't know about any other method to do this, especially using video card driver. 
If you could shed some light how to do that, I would be more than happy. Should I use GL_AMD_performance_monitor?
Max texture size is: 2048, I'm using also NPOT extension. Textures bigger than this are cut into maximum possible size, and surfaces using it are splitted into smaller, separate parts when needed. 
Draw call is: glDrawArrays().

Comment: Yes, you should use vendor-specific GL extensions or something like gDebugger. When you issuing GL calls, you actually filling command buffer, which driver fetches whenever it fits. Then these commands could be re-ordered or modified by any way, if it doesn't affect final result. So even glFinish doesn't mean drawing will be finished at the end of this call. I can't understand about texture sizes, though. You said that 2048 is max size, then what does "with texture over 2048" means? Anyway, in these situation you should see insane performance drop, so you need to reduce texture memory anyway.

Comment: Thanks for Your informations. I'll try to profile some more. And about the over "max texture size" textures - I'm splitting them into series of parts, of which every fits maximum size. And when I need to use them (in 2D mode) I just split needed element into subelements drawn with required part of texture. This allows me to have big textures even on very limited h/w. 

+1 for the gDebugger - Thank You very much.

Comment: Well, initial idea isn't bad at all, but how much vram you using? There is a difference between vram and GL's texture ram - when you trying to use texture that isn't in vram, GL will be forced to free some space and re-upload it to vram, which will be very slow if it happens every frame. I can't say about your particular hardware, but to be generic - GL always have a copy in system ram so vram could be restored without notice. Maybe that's what you see, and in that case - no matter what, you need to reduce vram footprint (by unloading unused textures, or by using texture compression, whatever)